# связь процесса node js и electron js

Tags: node.js, discord, electron

У меня есть дискорд-бот на discord.js, и приложение на electron.js, которые я хотел бы связать. Я знаю, что процессы node js вроде как связывать можно. Могу ли я обратится из запущенного приложения electron к процессу бота, и если могу, то как? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процессы должны связываться между собой какими-либо методами.
Зачастую связывание происходит через систему публикации сообщений - просто пакеты кастомных данных.
Группа этих методов называется IPC - Межпроцессное взаимодействие.
Здесь Вы можете найти сравнение популярных способов:
https://habr.com/ru/post/315200

В данной статье учитываются многие проблемы и вопросы, думаю, вы найдете подходящую технологию.

Comment: Спасибо. Я посмотрел, в итоге меня устроил вариант с ванильным api для этого